# Why is $-9 \cdot 26 \equiv -1 \cdot 26 \mod 103$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Instead of multiplying $-9$ and $26$ out, the professor got rid of a multiple of $9$ immediately before actually performing the next modular arithmetic step. What justifies this step of getting rid of the $9$ factor?

Comment: Maybe it is 104? Since -8*26=-208 which is divisible by 104.

Comment: Never trust math professors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This step isn't valid - we have $-9\cdot 26=-234$ and $-1\cdot 26=-26$, and $-234-(-26)=-208$ which isn't divisible by $103$.

EDIT: As Fermat suggested in a comment, you might have meant the modulus to be $104$. In that case, note that $104=4\cdot 26$, so $-9\cdot 26=-1\cdot 26-2\cdot 4\cdot 26=-1\cdot 26-2\cdot 104\equiv -1\cdot 26 (\mod 104)$.

Answer (score 1):

He probably didn't get rid of a multiple of $9$, he got rid of a multiple of $4$ because $4\cdot 26 = 104 \equiv 1 \mod 103$. So
$$
-9\cdot 26 \equiv (-4-4-1) \cdot 26 \equiv (-4)\cdot 26 +(-4)\cdot 26 +(-1)\cdot 26 \\
\equiv-1 -1 -26 \equiv -28 \mod 103
$$
Note that the relation you stated for the problem is not right.